# Range Hood Fan Wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, exhaust-fan

How do I connect the Red and Yellow wires from the fan to the Black and White wires from the power outlet?
The range hood also has one red wire coming from the fan switch - how is this connected to the fan?
The range hood is a Broan Model 58000.

[image]

[image: wiring photo from 2nd question]

Comment: The fan is typically wired into the switch as well as the lights, there should be a central control switch that you wire to the black and white supply wires and then everything is controlled by the switch in the range hood.

Comment: Thank you Alaska Man - I have posted a revised query. I was not sure on how to add a photo to this chain.....

Comment: You are missing a clamp or grommet where the NM cable enters the fan housing.

Answer (score 0):

From Looking at your other post.
With only 2 wires from the fan? I would connect switched hot and neutral. I would connect the 2 Red wires together with a wire nut.
Then the yellow  it needs to be connected to the neutrals wire nut.
The only thing odd is the neutral going towards the switch , if the hot jumps to a 2nd switch for a light then that would make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, Thank you nonetheless my friend.