# Help with Range Hood Wiring

Tags: exhaust-fan

I need help with wiring my range hood fan. My challenge is I need precise instructions on how to connect the 3 wires. Please see new range hood wiring diagram attached. How do I connect wires 1, 2 & 3 to the Hot and Neutral wires?  The hood has one switch for the light and one for the fan. The light works fine with the current configuration. I’m assuming the black wire coming out of the range hood is from the light switch.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your [other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198779/range-hood-fan-wiring) to include the updated picture instead of asking a whole new one.

Comment: @freeman The linked how to did not say how to.

Comment: No, it didn't, @EdBeal, but it's a 2nd question from the same person asking the exact same thing, but with the picture that was asked for on the original question. While technically not a "dupe" in that the other has an answer, I think it's well within the spirit of a "dupe" vote, and it's educational for a new user to understand how things work here - edit a question to provide the requested info, not start a whole new one.

Comment: That may be true but if  you would have said that it would have been clear and you can help by editing.

Comment: @EdBeal the "Does this answer your question?" comment is automatically generated when a post is flagged/VTC as a duplicate.

Comment: @yoozer8 I have voted to close many posts and unless you put something it is not automatically generated but I can see by your rep you really haven’t been here long

Comment: @EdBeal no, you can't. Please see the "What are automatic comments" portion of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/167443) which explains the automatically generated "Does this answer your question?" comments

Comment: @yoozer8 there was not an answer to that question until I left it , comments are also not for extended conversations.